# Have multiple actionButtons linked to the same verbatimTextOutput

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a shiny app with multiple actionButtons that render unique text to the same varbatimTextOutput. I'd like it to work like this, where buttons 1 and 2 would print different text to the same place:

[image]

Here's what I tried:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("button1", "Button 1"),
  actionButton("button2", "Button 2"),
  verbatimTextOutput("button_out", placeholder = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  button_out <- eventReactive({
    input$button1
    }
    ,{
      paste0("You pressed button 1!")
    }) 
  
  button_out <- eventReactive({
    input$button2
    }
    ,{
      paste0("You pressed button 2!")
    }) 
  
  output$button_out <- renderText({
    button_out()
    })
}
  
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I was expecting this to allow both actionButtons to output to the same place, but instead only Button 2 works, I guess because the code for that is overwriting the code for button 1. I considered putting an if statement in eventReactive, but I'm not exactly sure how to do it?

Is there a way to do this that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is use `reactiveValues` object.  Try this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("button1", "Button 1"),
  actionButton("button2", "Button 2"),
  verbatimTextOutput("button_out", placeholder = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(val=NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$button1, {
    rv$val <- paste0("You pressed button 1!")
  }) 
  
  observeEvent(input$button2, {
    rv$val <- paste0("You pressed button 2!")
  })
  
  output$button_out <- renderText({
    rv$val
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

@YBS's answer is nice.

Another way is to use the `onclick` attribute of the buttons. This attribute allows to execute some JavaScript code each time the button is clicked. Then with this JavaScript code you can send a Shiny input value to the server with `Shiny.setInputValue`

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(
    "button1", "Button 1", 
    onclick = "Shiny.setInputValue('button', 1);"
  ),
  actionButton(
    "button2", "Button 2", 
    onclick = "Shiny.setInputValue('button', 2);"
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("button_out", placeholder = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$button_out <- renderText({
    paste0("You clicked on button ", input$button) 
  })
}
  
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Awesome!  This method will be very useful in certain situations.